# how can ipad with IOS 7.0.4 work on Xcode 4.6 - or restore from IOS 7 to IOS 6.1.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios6, ios7

I develop on ipad IOS 6.1.3 on XCode 4.6.
By mistake, ipad was updated to IOS 7.0.4.

So, How can I make iPad with IOS 7.0.4 works on Xcode 4.6 ?
Or, How can I restore iPad from IOS 7 to IOS 6.1.3 ?

My Mac os is 10.7.5

I can't complete my work..

Thank you

Comment: That need to update mac os from 10.7.5 to 10.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very soon Apple will stop accepting apps that are built using Xcode 4.6, so you'll want to work on your app using Xcode 5, unless you don't plan on releasing your app.

As for downgrading your iPad, I don't think that's possible any longer. It used to be possible to downgrade from iOS 7 beta versions to iOS 6, but I think once iOS 7 was officially released that it is no longer possible.

My suggestion would be to upgrade your Mac OS version so you can install Xcode 5, and continue development. If you want users to use your app, they'll want it to be built with Xcode 5 so that it has the new iOS look anyway. After using iOS 7 for a while, apps that have the iOS 6 look still seem very dated.